# Python - Outputting a dict with many values to one key

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project where I am trying to parse some data and output it. I have managed to parse it but have reached a hurdle.

The parser outputs a dict that looks like this:

```
{'view_name': {'name': 'currencies_dim'}, 'dimension': {'type': 'STRING', 'sql_table_name': 'currency_pk', 'hidden': 'yes', 'name': 'currency_pk'}}
{'view_name': {'name': 'currencies_dim'}, 'dimension': {'type': 'NUMERIC', 'sql_table_name': 'currency_natural_key', 'hidden': 'yes', 'name': 'currency_natural_key'}}
{'view_name': {'name': 'currencies_dim'}, 'dimension': {'type': 'STRING', 'sql_table_name': 'currency_name', 'hidden': 'yes', 'name': 'currency_name'}}
{'view_name': {'name': 'currencies_dim'}, 'dimension': {'type': 'STRING', 'sql_table_name': 'symbol', 'hidden': 'yes', 'name': 'symbol'}}
```

The desired output is one view_name to many dimensions.

The problem is the parser outputs dimensions one-to-one with views. I have a limited understanding of python but I am under the understanding a dict can only have one value set to one key. So this makes sense as expected behaviour...

Would anyone have recommendations over how to get the desired output?

My ideas are:

Somehow group dimensions by key and use this as an output. Hopefully looking like this:

```
 {'view_name': {'name': 'currencies_dim'},

'dimension': {'type': 'STRING', 'sql_table_name': 'symbol', 'hidden': 'yes', 'name': 'symbol'}}
'dimension': {'type': 'NUMERIC', 'sql_table_name': 'currency_natural_key', 'hidden': 'yes', 'name': 'currency_natural_key'}}
'dimension': {'type': 'STRING', 'sql_table_name': 'currency_name', 'hidden': 'yes', 'name': 'currency_name'}}
'dimension': {'type': 'STRING', 'sql_table_name': 'symbol', 'hidden': 'yes', 'name': 'symbol'}}
```

2. Perhaps make the dict a list somehow. I don't know if this makes sense or not.

Many thanks for any input.

Comment: You can't have the same key multiple times in a dictionary.  But you can have the value be a list.  I.e. the value associated with the key `'dimension'` would be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: The keys in a dictionary needs to be unique, so in that sense it is a one-to-one binding between the keys and values. Although the values are just objects and can be lists or any other object. If i understand the example correctly, you want the name ```currencies_dim``` bound to all elements in dimension?

Comment: @Kevin - That's correct. The aim being all of the dimensions are grouped to currency

Comment: @James - Ah, understood. Is this a process for making a list out of a value?

Comment: Is the output from the parser a string or is it a python object? If it is a python object, it will not be interpreted as expected.

Comment: @Kevin - The output is a python object. I think I'm doing something abnormal upstream as not many other people seem to hit this issue aha